# Insert into a newly created table using enterprise library without refreshing the existing edmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, enterprise-library

Here is the case:

I have an existing project created using entity framework.
Now I have to create a new form and save its data to a new table using enterprise library.
But the catch is that I have to do it without refreshing the existing edmx of the project.
When I am calling the insert query, its showing the error:

```
    The type Database cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it myself. just need to create a different connection string for using enterprise library. since the previous connection string had the property of entity framework as well, that's why it was showing the error. :)